# C# .net backgroundworker thread not closing handles

Tags: c#

I have a `backgroundworker` thread in my `c#` application that extracts files from a compressed file.

I notice that the `backgroundworker` does complete.

If I then attempt to delete the directory where the files where extracted to, by the `backgroundworker`, I get an `IOException`, telling me that the directory and files are in use.

I used `processexplorer.exe` and the process is my C# application. I attempted to call and ensure the `backgroundworker` was `.CancelAsync()` and `.Dispose()`. I don't understand why the handle is still on the files?

If I close my app and start it up again, the files are deleted upon startup from the temp location they were extracted to, as I have code upon startup of my app to clean out any extracted files from a temp location.

It seems I cannot find anyway to completely delete directories and files that I know I created by extracting them from a compressed file, and that my app has a thread that still has open handles to said files and directories.

Is there anyway I can forcible delete these directories and files, knowing I am responsible for their creation and current handle to them?

here is my code for the external .exe that is decompressing the compressed files, i was not using a "using" block to begin with but changed it and didn't not help.

```
 using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = param;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.Start();

            StreamReader reader = proc.StandardOutput;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());
            }
            reader.Close();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
```

Comment: Any file streams should be inside of a `using()` block to prevent things like this.

Comment: In 20+ years in the salt mines I've known a staggering number of things for a fact. About 90% of them were hopeless delusions. HOW do you "know this for a fact"? Why are you calling Dispose() instead of using a `using` block which is *guaranteed* to call Dispose()? Can you trace through the worker thread code in the debugger and reach the Dispose() call? Can we SEE your code?

Comment: I'm with caesay - put the file handling code in a Using, then do what you need with the files. Also - its best practice.

Comment: Do you get the same issue, if you do the work on main thread instead of backgroundworker? If yes, the issue lies somewhere else (as others have suggested, probably you haven't disposed your filestream related stuff).

Comment: Issue doesn't happen in main thread, and i put the Process function call that i have for the un-compression .exe into a using block. didn't seem to help. the BW just calls my external .exe i have and decompresses multiple files. after it all said and before I attempt to click on my button to execute code again, i look at process explorer tool i DL and i see handles to every single file that was extracted into my temp folder for each file that was decompressed.

i edited my comment to include code i use to run the external .exe that decompresses files into my temp folder

Comment: Then your external EXE needs fixing. As my answer states, anything doing file I/O needs to properly clean up after itself. There are ways to force the release of files, but it requires Windows API calls, which is a bit extreme. If you have access to the source of the external app, then fix it.

Comment: i'm using 7z.exe from 7zip :)

Comment: @johnjohnson Is the process completing? What is the value for `param`?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing how you are dealing with the decompression, it's not immediately obvious what is happening. However, getting rid of the BackgroundWorker doesn't deal with everything inside of it. Instead, inside of the work being done, you should be properly closing files, releasing handles, etc. The worker thread had the instance, but the application owns the handle. When the thread ends, it's still possible to retain open handles. Make sure things like `File.Close()` are being done. If you do this, your application (or anything outside of it) will be able to continue with the delete.